# how to get redirect url using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
r = requests.get('http://techtv.mit.edu/videos/1585-music-session-02/download.source') 
for i in r.history:
    print(i.url)
```

I think it should print out the history, but it doesn't, the above url points to a video, but I cannot get it, anyone help? Thank you

Comment: What should the history that it prints out be?

Comment: I am looking for real url, not history, but I am printing history, my mistake.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To get the resultant URL after you've been redirected, you can do `r.url`.

```
r = requests.get('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ') 
print(r.url) # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtu.be
```

`r.history` is for URLs prior to the final one, so it's only returning your original URL because you were only redirected once.

Comment: it really helps me with google news scrapping

Comment: failed for this "https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://news.cmlviz.com/2018/11/12/the-repeating-pattern-in-wipro-limited-that-triggers-right-after-an-earnings-beat-and-the-option-trade-thatfollows.html&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGmMyMzNjMDg2NDBlY2NhMDE6Y29tOmVuOlVT&usg=AFQjCNF14hJZaV0rXun1oZV4RJlOVF6eaA"

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, wouldn't this make a request to the redirected URL unnecessarily (waste bandwidth and time) when we only want the redirect URL string without actually making a request to the redirect URL?

Comment: @ritiek It won't actually read any data from the socket so it won't waste bandwidth (beyond reading the header). You could do `requests.head` instead to do a HEAD request, but this doesn't always work, as it depends on if the server is set up properly.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it just prints out the original MIT link.  Has something in `requests` changed in the last 3 years ... ?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Does it not work at all, or only on the example MIT link? The MIT link relies on JavaScript to do anything now and therefore doesn't redirect when used with requests. It still works with links that redirect via the header/HTTP status code 30X. I'll edit the answer with a working link.

Comment: @TurunAmbartanen I'm really sorry but I don't remember anymore .. maybe one of the people who up-voted my comment can explain?  (Sorry to be so unhelpful!)

Comment: IT STILLS WORKING. Thank you so much!

Comment: check my solution using webbrowser library here. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503861/to-get-redirected-url-with-requests/70869177#70869177)

Comment: @ritiek You're right, using this method always "wastes" one extra request but is needed to check for further redirections. If you know the exact number of redirects make the first request then do ```r.next.url``` to get redirect URL. If needed create a session and send ```r.next``` n-1 times.