# Python - How to get the page Wikipedia will redirect me to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, redirect

I want to store a few different Wikipedia links but I don't want to store two different links to the same page twice. For example the following links are different but they point to the same Wikipedia page:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=(1S)-1-Methyl-2,3,4,9-tetrahydro-1H-pyrido-3,4-b-indole&redirect=no 
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=(1S)-1-methyl-2,3,4,9-tetrahydro-1H-pyrido-3,4-b-indole&redirect=no
__________________________________________________|___________________________________________________________
```

The only difference is that one uppercase character. Or the following links:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(0,1)-matrix 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(0,1)_matrix 
___________________________________|______
```

That are only different because one has '-' and the other has '_'(' '). So what I want is storing only one of them or the following links:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydroharman 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix
```

I have already tried the answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070821/how-to-get-redirect-url-using-python-requests). But it didn't work for me. (The result is the initial URL for me, not the one wiki redirects me to in the browser) So how can I achieve what I'm looking for!?

Comment: Could you please explain what result you exactly get by trying the solution in the SO question you linked to and which of the solutions you tried exactly!?

Comment: @aran I used the accepted answer and I already explained what I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Wikipedia doesn't have a proper 301/302 redirection what happens when you open the link is a proper 200 success response is returned and then url is changed using JS

I came up with a quick workable solution. First, remove `&redirect=no` from the URL

```
In [42]: import requests

In [43]: r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=(1S)-1-Met
    ...: hyl-2,3,4,9-tetrahydro-1H-pyrido-3,4-b-indole')

In [44]: tmp = r.content.replace('<link rel="canonical" href="', 'r@ndom}-=||').
    ...: split('r@ndom}-=||')[-1]

In [45]: idx = tmp.find('"/>')

In [46]: real_link = tmp[:idx]

In [47]: real_link
Out[47]: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydroharman'
```

The real URL value is stored in `<link rel="canonical" href="` tag.

You can use above method which is good enough for your use case or you can use libraries like bs4 to parse the page and the get the link or use regex the extract the link.

Comment: Is there no other way to do it without a get request!? since get requests are rather heavy-weight:-?

Comment: is 'r@ndom}-=||' just something that you are sure won't already exist in text!?

Comment: btw I think you should change .content to .text

Comment: @thegod since the url comes from page content, no there is no lighter way. Yes, r@ndom}-=|| is some random string I added. It should not be in page content. You can make it more variable.

Answer (score 6):

The [MediaWiki Action API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) provides various endpoints used in Wikipedia. You can query the endpoint https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php to get the target page of a redirect.

You can retrieve the result as JSON and parse it to get the value of the element **to** or the element **title**

**Example:**

This query will retrieve the target page for 'Halab' city:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Halab&redirects&format=json

Result:

```
{  
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{  
      "redirects":[  
         {  
            "from":"Halab",
            "to":"Aleppo"
         }
      ],
      "pages":{  
         "159244":{  
            "pageid":159244,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Aleppo"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In Python:

```
import json
import requests

query = requests.get(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={}&redirects&format=json'.format('Halab'))

data = json.loads(query.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Amit Tripathi throws an exception. this is my answer:

```
res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)
for t in doc.xpath("//link[contains(@rel, 'canonical')]"):
    new_url = str(t.attrib['href'])
```

from my experience, there might be a redirection to the same url. so better check (url != new_url) before using new_url.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution using the [`wikipedia`](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/) library:

```py
>>> import wikipedia
>>> page = wikipedia.page(title="(0,1)_matrix", redirect=True)
>>> page.title
'Logical matrix'
```