# How can I retrieve the final redirect link of a Wikipedia page?

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, wikipedia

I am attempting to write a Python script that retrieves the final redirect link of a Wikipedia page. For example, when accessing "`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzzzzz`", it should return "`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_(joke_line)`".

I have the following code that works for getting the redirect of any link and also works with the YouTube URL shortener, but it doesn't seem to work with Wikipedia links:

```py
import requests

def get_final_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    if response.status_code in (300, 301, 302, 303, 307, 308):
        return response.headers['Location']
    else:
        return None

initial_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzzzzz"  # Replace with your URL
final_url = get_final_url(initial_url)
print("Final URL:", final_url)
```

```py
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzzzzz -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzzzzz
https://youtu.be/nMFv8YPOQdY -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMFv8YPOQdY&feature=youtu.be
```

Comment: I tried to see how that Zzzzzz url ended at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_(joke_line), and the only reference to it was in the body content. This answer seems to suggest the same approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47537837/190902

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to get the page Wikipedia will redirect me to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537644/python-how-to-get-the-page-wikipedia-will-redirect-me-to)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up working for me:

```py
import requests, json

def get_final_url(name):
    url = f'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={name}&redirects&format=json'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return json.loads(response.text)["query"]["redirects"][0]["to"]

initial_url = "Zzzzzz"  # Replace with your URL
final_url = get_final_url(initial_url)
print(final_url)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).