# To get redirected URL with requests

Tags: python, url, redirect, python-requests

I want to get redırected URL with requests. My URL is https://twitter.com/i/user/2274951674 . When I enter this url my browser, The URL redirect https://twitter.com/ozanbayram01

```
r=requests.get("https://twitter.com/i/user/2274951674")`

r.url #doesnt work
```

Comment: did you try reading the documentation?  I believe they mention r.history

Comment: Yes, I did but it doesn't work and it return empty lists.

Comment: `r.url` should be the url that was _requested_.  To look at redirects in the response, use `r.history`.

Comment: Yes, I did but it doesn't work and it return empty lists

Comment: It's not redirecting.  I suspect it's just using javascript or something else to modify the url in your browser. Perhaps use selenium and capture the url in the browser after the page finishes loading.

Comment: Is there any way without using selenium? I can use requests-html instead of requests.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any luck to get redirected url back by using requests as mentioned in previous posts. But I was able to work around this using webbrowser library and then get the browser history using sqlite 3 and was able to get the result that you are looking for.

let me know if you found another solutions.

here is my code:

```
import webbrowser
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import shutil

webbrowser.open("https://twitter.com/i/user/2274951674")
#source file is where the history of your webbroser is saved, I was using chrome, but it should be the same process if you are using different browser
source_file = 'C:\\Users\\{your_user_id}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History'
# could not directly connect to history file as it was locked and had to make a copy of it in different location
destination_file = 'C:\\Users\\{user}\\Downloads\\History'
time.sleep(30) # there is some delay to update the history file, so 30 sec wait give it enough time to make sure your last url get logged
shutil.copy(source_file,destination_file) # copying the file.
con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\{user}\\Downloads\\History')#connecting to browser history
cursor = con.execute("SELECT * FROM urls")
names = [description[0] for description in cursor.description]
urls = cursor.fetchall()
con.close()
df_history = pd.DataFrame(urls,columns=names)
last_url = df_history.loc[len(df_history)-1,'url']
print(last_url)

>>https://twitter.com/ozanbayram01
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the relevant part in the Requests documentation.](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Use the `history` attribute of the `Response` object. It's a list of `Response` objects starting from oldest to most recent. So if from-here.com redirects to to-there.com, then it looks like this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get('https://from-here.com')
>>> res.url
'https://from-here.com'
>>> res.history[0]
<Response [302]>
>>> res.history[0].url
'https://to-there.com'
```